# What am I not understanding? Given 9 integers, choose 4 a, b, c, d such that a + b − c − d is divisible by 20.

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

What am I misunderstanding? A question on this site asks [Given any nine integers show that it is possible to choose, from among them, four integers a, b, c, d such that a + b − c − d is divisible by 20.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659207/given-any-nine-integers-show-that-it-is-possible-to-choose-from-among-them-fou)

(i) Let's try these nine positive integers

```
   1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

and assign any four of them to a,b,c,d

```
   (1 + 1 - 1 - 1)
```

Is this divisible by 20?

(ii) Try these nine non-equal positive integers

```
   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

The highest value of a + b is (9 + 8). Even before we subtract, we have a maximum 17 div 20 = 0 and a non-zero remainder.

Which four values from (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) can be chosen?

Alternatively, why do these examples not fit the question?

Comment: $0$ is also divisible by $20$

Comment: @drhab This was the source of my misunderstanding, all is now clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $(i),$ yes, $0$ is divisible by $20.$
For $(ii),$ we can choose $20\mid (9+1-2-8)=0.$
So these numbers do fit in the question indeed.